# How can I minify css file containing @import url lines

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am using grunt-contrib-cssmin to minify my css files but onw of my css files is using @import url lines and above mentioned grunt plugin is unable to minify this css file. I have also tried clean-css and cssjoin tools to solve this problem but nothing has worked until know.

**

- Grunt File:

**

```
grunt.initConfig({
        // Metadata
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        cssmin: {
          minified_css_admin: {
              files: {
                  'public/admin/css/minified-css-admin.min.css'     ['public/admin/prettify/prettify.css','public/admin/css/developer.css']
              }
          }

        }
    });
    // These plugins provide necessary tasks

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');


    // Default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['admin-default']);
    grunt.registerTask('admin-default', ['cssmin:minified_css_admin']);
};
```

**

- Prettify.css

**

```
@import url('bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('bootstrap-responsive.min.css');
@import url('uniform.tp.css');
@import url('jquery.ui.css');
@import url('colorpicker.css');
@import url('colorbox.css');
@import url('jquery.jgrowl.css');
@import url('jquery.alerts.css');
@import url('animate.min.css');
@import url('animate.delay.css');
@import url('font-awesome.css');
@import url('jquery.tagsinput.css');
@import url('ui.spinner.css');
@import url('jquery.chosen.css');
@import url('fullcalendar.css');
@import url('font-awesome-ie7.css');
@import url('../fonts/roboto.css');


/***** RESET BROWSER STYLES *****/
/********************************/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: In what way is it unable to minify them? Does it break the import statements in some way?

Comment: No, running grunt-contrib-cssmin gets hanged and displays no result

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/issues/75 cssmin requires that you set the root directory in order for it to retain relative @import URLs.

```
   cssmin: {
        options: {
            report: 'min',
            root: '../../webroot',
       }
   }
```